# how can i pass variables with facebook auth link while using laravel 5.1 and Socialite class?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, laravel-socialite

i am building a referral links to my users and i wanna pass a variables with the facebook Auth link like so :

`<a  href="{{ route('facebook.auth', ['id' => $id,'code'=>$code]) }} ></a>`

i have tried to build a link tracker like so

```
    public function trackLink($id=null,$code=null)
{

if (User::where('id',$id)->where('referral_code',$code)->first()) {

        $points = Points::where('user_id',$id)->first();
        $points->user_id    = $id;
        $points->points     = Points::where('user_id',$id)->first()->points + 1000;
        $points->save();

    }

    return redirect()->route('auth.facebook');
}
```

and i redirected the user to it but this repeat the points to the user each log in attempt

how do i send these variables with the auth link.